# array of contracts and contructor with arguments

Tags: contract-development, constructor

Strange behavior. I have the following pair of smart contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract Zone
{
  string public a;
  string public b;
  string public c;
  string public d;

  constructor(string memory _a,
              string memory _b,
              string memory _c,
              string memory _d)
  {
    a=_a;
    b=_b;
    c=_c;
    d=_d;
  }
}

contract Hc
{ 
  Zone[] zones;
  
  function toto() external 
  { 
    zones.push(new Zone("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"));
  }
/*
  function titi() external view returns (string memory)
  { 
    return zones[0].c();
  } 
*/
}
```

When I call "toto" in the JS code, it works. However, if I uncomment the function "titi", it fails with "execution reverted" even if I do not call "titi".

The JS call of toto is the following:

```
async function toto(){
        await contract.methods.toto().call().catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
        }).then(function (toto){
                console.log(toto)
        })
}
```

In some other tests, we tried to return a value of zones from toto and it worked flawlessly. But once outside toto the array of Zones becomes empty again.

Any idea why it does not work?
Many thanks,
eric